# SVG width in Opera Mobile not bigger than 800px

Tags: mobile, xhtml, svg, opera-mobile

I have SVG with width set to 2048px and I want it display in Opera Mobile (with possibility to scroll horizontally if it is bigger than screen), but for some reason Opera is always displaying the SVG with width = 800px and scaling down the SVG. This happens only on a real device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 - resolution 1280x800). This happen also in horizontal mode - in which screen width is equal to 1280px so the SVG is even SMALLER than a screen. On the other hand on the Opera Mobile emulator it has the width set to 1280px (still no scroll but it's better).

I also tried to place SVG in div with some fixed sizes but without success - the size of div is correct but SVG is scaled down...

Are there any way to render a page with horizontal scrollbar? Or workaround the bug which causes the SVG in horizontal mode set to the width of shorter dimension?

You can check the example here: http://www.pax.ndl.pl/test/svg_temp.xhtml

Comment: Why do you want to do so at all? SVG is used in cases where yuo need an scalable graphic. It contradicts the intention of a SVG to set it to a fixed width…

Comment: it is a kind of SVG editor which I want to go mobile

Comment: Read this: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

Comment: Sadly, this does not work :/ I think it may be Opera bug as on emulator it looks all right